# difference results between 10**-2 and E-2

Tags: fortran90, gfortran, fortran95

The following program print 1 for `100E-2` and gives 0 for `100*10**(-2)`, that means that
the operator exponent doesnot work for negative `**`, is that correct.
Thanks in advance

```
program testme

implicit none

print*,100E-2

print*,100*10**(-2)

end program
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll notice that the second print statement prints `0` -- no decimal pt, etc.   Eg, integer zero.   That's because `10` by itself is an integer literal, and raising that to the negative 2 power correctly gives zero; multiplying it by integer 100 still gives integer zero.

If you instead use

```
print*,100*10.**(-2)
```

you'll get the answer you expect.

The issue doesn't arise with `100e-2` because any number expressed with scientific notation is  a floating point (`real`) literal.

Comment: so you mean that the base of the power needs to be real. But in the same time when I tires the following print*,100*10**(2) it works well without making the base a real.

Comment: That's because integer 10 times integer 10 is (integer) 100, but integer 1 divided by (integer 10 times integer 10) is integer zero.